# What function rule maps $0,1,2,3,4,5$ to respective values $0,1,4,3,4,1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I'm reading Edwin Moise's book Elementary Geometry from an Advanced Standpoint (3rd edition) and in section 3.2 The Set-Theoretic Interpretation of Functions and Relations there's the following passage:

"Consider first the case where the domain is a finite set, say,

| A |
| --- |
| A = {0, 1,2,3,4,5} |

For any function f with A as domain, we can write down a complete table, giving
the values of the function f.

| a | f(a) |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 1 |

There was a system used in making up the table; and you may be able to figure out what this system was. But even if you can't figure it out, the function is defined by the table."

I'm trying to figure out what system was used in making up the table, but I couldn't find it untill now. Could anyone help me? Can you find what system was used? I suppose by "system" the author meant the function rule which assigns for each element "a ∊ A" it's value "f(a)".

ps. I know it's just a passage in the book and has no importance at all, but hey, we all love math and want to know everything we possibily can, right?!

Comment: As you said it isn't important that there is a rule, but in this case it looks like $f$ is squaring mod $6$. That is $f(a)$ is the remainder of $a^2$ divided by $6$.

Comment: There are infinitely many distinct functions $\mathbf{R} \to \mathbf{R}$ whose restriction to $\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ is these set of values. Fishbane's formula works, but here's another: $$f(x) = -\frac{x^5}{5}+\frac{5 x^4}{2}-11 x^3+\frac{39 x^2}{2}-\frac{49 x}{5}$$ Which is the unique polynomial of lowest degree that interpolates between these values.

Comment: @Fishbane You should probably post that as an answer, not a comment.

Comment: Interpolating is the obvious approach. I find it good that it was only posted as a comment.

Comment: $f(x) = \left|x-3\right|^{3}-5\left|x-3\right|^{2}+5\left|x-3\right|+3$ or one of practically infinitely many possible rules.

Answer (score 0):

From [OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=0%2c1%2c4%2c3%2c4%2c1&start=10), one possible solution is $n^2 \pmod{6}$.

Alternatively, another solution can be $n^4 \pmod{6}$. There are many other rules that defined it.

The whole point of the paragraph is just by listing the domain and image pair, the function is well-defined.